# how to consolidate information from various rows in to 1 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server called [orders]:

[image]

I have another table called [order_details]:

[image]

as you can see, if the media_type is various in [orders] table, there will be 2 corresponding rows in [order_details].

how can i make the below table?

[image]

i was trying the method that the admins suggested even before they closed down my original question but what i was getting was the below:

[image]

i need this to be like:

[image]

Comment: The admins didn't close your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189572/how-to-return-values-from-2-rows-into-1-in-sql-server), I did. Asking how to pivot data in SQL Server has been asked many times, and the duplicate I have you shows you exactly how you do that. And, surprise, Gordon has shown you exactly what a `PIVOT` is, so the closure was completely warranted... Also, if you *really* had searched "the whole internet" you would have already answered your question. There are literally Exabytes of information on the internet.

Comment: with all due respect, i did not ask for a pivot. to be absolutely honest with you, pivot does not work for me. you would use pivot if you want to change rows into columns, that is not what i want to do. i have pre-designated columns which i need to be filled with the information from another table based on the criteria i set. does that make sense?

Comment: Also, with respect, if you really are working to such a tight schedule, then you should be using the internal resources in the company to reach the dead line. Stack Overflow Users are hear to quickly turn around an answer for you because you are time constrained; it isn't a "free coding service".

Comment: *"ith all due respect, i did not ask for a pivot."* That is *exactly* what you are asking for: *"how to consolidate information from various rows in to 1"*. That is a pivot.

Comment: Also, please do take the time to post same data in a consumable format. Images don't help us he[p you. The best format is DDL and DML statements, however, if not then provide tabular format `text`, so we can at least copy your data and make our own statements.

Comment: oh ok sorry if format was incorrect. I am very very tired as this has taken away all my mental powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would just perform an aggregation on the query that got you these results

```
select [order id]
       ,max(pallets)         as pallets
       ,max([total cartons]) as [total cartons]
       ,max(units)           as units
       ,max(sets)            as sets
       ,max(GOH)             as GOH
       ,max([Loose Cartons]) as [Loose Cartons]
       ,max([Loose Units])   as [Loose Units]
  from (<insert query that got you the results with two records >
       )
group by [order id]
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, by editing your question.

Comment: Its impossible that it would return two rows with the same [order id], since its "grouped by" the [order id]. so there would be exactly one record per [order id]

Answer (score 3):

You seem to just want conditional aggregation on `order_details`:

```
select od.order_id,
       sum(case when od.media_type = 'Loose Cartons' then qty else 0 end) as loose_cartons,
       sum(case when od.media_type = 'Loose Units' then qty else 0 end) as loose_units
from order_details od
group by od.order_id;
```

Comment: `IMTMS_ORDER.ORDER_DATE` isn't in Gordon's statement, @P.MAJ .

Comment: ok i will post all of my script above, warning given its very very long. the solution by Gordon was to add the sum(case... statement with a group by clause. i done that and i got the error. will edit my main post in a sec

Comment: There is also no column `ORDER_DATE` in your sample data, @P.MAJ . It seems you are only giving us one slice of the pie, but expecting us to deal with the whole lot.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry you are right. as i said it is a very complicated process. i have many many more columns to add. the only bit i need help with is that when i needs to lookup the "Various" type of media from another table. i am not sure why they ve done it like this, but i have to deal with it. the idea is to say if the media type was various, then look at the breakdown and bring back the results of 3 media types: pallets, cartons and sets in 1 row. as i am also using them 3 columns for something else, i can not use pivot.

Comment: Likely you need to either aggregate the column, or add it to your `GROUP BY`, @P.MAJ (impossible to know without full sample data and expected results). I can still, however, assure you that what you are after is a `PIVOT` or Cross Tab (as Gordon shows here), and if you take the time to read up on them, you'll be able to expand the solution here, and the prior duplicate I gave you, to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys sorted.

So i had to create a separate table with just the order_id and 3 more columns with Pallets, Cartons and Sets.

i had to use "max" not "sum" otherwise it would double the quantity.

so what i used was:

```
create view SSDView_2ND_VB as
select 
    a.ORDER_ID 
    ,max(case when b.MEDIATYPE_ID = '1' then b.ORDER_DETAIL_QUANTITY else null end) as [Pallets]
    ,max(case when b.MEDIATYPE_ID = '2' then b.ORDER_DETAIL_QUANTITY else null end) as [Cartons]
    ,max(case when b.MEDIATYPE_ID = '3' then b.ORDER_DETAIL_QUANTITY else null end) as [Sets]
from
    SSDView_1ST_VB as a
        left join ORDER_DETAIL as b 
        on a.ORDER_ID = b.ORDER_ID
group by a.ORDER_ID
```

The SSDView_1ST_VB was just another view which only had media type 'VARIOUS'.

I would like to thank you all for your help, really appreciate it guys ^^